# Contour plot with labels using the Visit plotting software and data set in vtk format

Tags: vtk

I am trying to make a contour plot labels in Visit. The initial file format I am using is VTK. The data is on a regular spaced rectangular grid

Visit offer a contour option, however it is not possible to add any labels. 
My idea is to make a contour plot, use the cut operator and create a 2D slice that looks something like this :
[image]

I know how to use the pseudo color option and overlay the contour curves, however I have no idea how to put labels on the curves. This is a standard graph type and I am assuming that this should be possible. 
I tried using a label plot, but this does not solve the problem.

I was reading online that python can plot VTK data, however, I have no experience with this python library.